Ffmpeg webm YouTube settings command
Is there a .webm still image command in ffmpeg that is best compatible with YouTube I’m currently using:
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i input.png -i audio.m4a -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv
But I want to know if there is a specific still image .webm YouTube settings? Can someone help me by giving me the command
I’ve found this:
ffmpeg -i “input.png” -i “audio file” -c:v libvpx-vp9 -lossless 1 output.webm 

But not sure if that is the best compatible YouTube settings

What are you trying to do...  -framerate 2?   What's the goal?

I got this command line: ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i input.png -i audio.m4a -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv from ffmpeg website to use the best still image compatible to YouTube it’s mkv but is there one for .webm best compatible with YouTube? Any ffmpeg webm YouTube specific settings command. Please help. I hope you understand?

Well, those settings are fine for .webm  Try: ffmpeg -i input.png -i audio.m4a -loop 1 -vf "format=yuv420p" -c:v h264 -crf 18 -c:a copy -avoid_negative_ts auto -shortest -movflags +faststart output.webm

Thank You. You have answered my question.
